# Spark Broadcast Variable

Tags: apache-spark

I tried the following code

```
val t1 = sc.parallelize(0 until 10)
val t2 = sc.broadcast(2)
val t3 = t1.filter(_ % t2.value == 0).persist()
t3.count()
t2.destroy()
t3.count()
```

It complains that "attempted to use Broadcast after it was destroyed" in the second `t3.count()`, which makes me confused. If I understand correctly, we call `persist` on `t3` and thus after the first `t3.count()`, `t3` is stored in memory. If so, `t3` does not need to be recomputed in the second `t3.count()` and it should be safe to destroy `t2`. But it seems that this is not true. I wonder what happens here.

Comment: I can also confirm this with Spark 2.4.5

Comment: I retested with spark 2.4.5 its working fine as below mentioned answer. @RaphaelRoth you mean to see its reproduced with spark 2.4.5 ? I used in my local with intellij <scala.version>2.11.12</scala.version>
        <spark.version>2.4.5</spark.version>

Comment: I think you are right. when I tried with spark 2.4.0 spark-shell then its giving me exception.. But Why Intellij maven scala local its working fine is the question. Seems like this is bug in spark. or might be some other reason I could not able to judge with this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Question*** : It complains that "attempted to use Broadcast after it was destroyed" in the second t3.count(), which makes me confused. If I understand correctly, we call persist on t3 and thus after the first t3.count(), t3 is stored in memory. If so, t3 does not need to be recomputed in the second t3.count() and it should be safe to destroy t2. But it seems that this is not true.

---

- **with spark-shell with spark 2.4.0, I am also getting the same error.**

*But surprisingly, intellij local maven scala project (with Spark 2.4.5 and Spark 2.2.2 ) *with use Case of `cache`/`persist`* I am NOT getting this 
Exception. 
There might be issue in spark or may be some other reason.*

***CASE 1 : With out using cache /persist calling destroy***

```
  val t1 = sc.parallelize(0 until 10)
  val t2 = sc.broadcast(2)
  val t3 = t1.filter(_ % t2.value == 0)
  println(t3.count())
  t2.destroy()
  println(t3.count())
```

Since it is not `cache` or`persist`ed you will get below result
Result :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Attempted to use Broadcast(0) after it was destroyed (destroy at BroadCastCheck.scala:20) 
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.assertValid(Broadcast.scala:144)
```

***Case2 : With using cache /persist calling destroy***.
Use Case with  `cache`/`persist` : The dataframe t3 will not be recomputed. hence no error after `destroy`

```
 val t1 = sc.parallelize(0 until 10)
  val t2 = sc.broadcast(2)
  val t3 = t1.filter(_ % t2.value == 0).cache // or persist as well  
  println(t3.count())
  t2.destroy()
  println(t3.count())
```

Result :

```
5

5
```

Comment: My example includes "persist" and the error still exists. So maybe it is caused by the version of Spark? I use Spark 2.2.3 and Scala 2.10.7.

Comment: @Kenny are you using spark-shell ? or spark-submit for testing this

Comment: I ran the example in Intellij. So may be it is the problem.

Comment: From intellij was it successful?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. :(